# ng-controller and ui-view doesn't work on the same element

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am using AngularJS and ui-router. My code has ng-controller and ui-view on the same element and the controller doesn't get triggered

http://plnkr.co/edit/UphvqV01R7m0WwlY67YA?p=preview

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script data-semver="1.2.7" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.7/angular.js" data-require="angular.js@1.2.x"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.0/angular-ui-router.js"></script>

    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div ui-view="main" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
      <p>Hello {{name}}!</p>  
    </div>

  </body>

</html>
```

**Javascript:**

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', '$locationProvider', function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {
  $stateProvider
    .state("home", {
      url: "^",
      resolve: {
        test: function() {
          alert("Triggered resolve home");
          return true;
        }
      }
    })
}]);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
});
```

Can you help to fix it or explain why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to have your main module ultimately dependent on `'ui.router'` somehow.  Right now you have it dependent on nothing (`[]`).

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ui.router']);
```

Comment: Forgot to add that but my "real" code had it. Still, doesn't fix the problem

Comment: When I add that to the plunkr it says "Hello World!" and gives the alert; What seems to be the issue with the code in the plunkr?

Answer (score 3):

Don't do this.

When you transition to a state, `ui.router` assigns a controller to each active `uiView` element, so any controller you had previously assigned would be replaced.

Just wrap the `uiView` in a parent element and apply the controller to that.

Also, as Words Like Jared has pointed out, you're not even importing the `ui.router` module, so you need to do that, too.

Comment: OK so basically ui-view and ng-controller in the same element is bad practice then?